# Artifactory, blocking error with Jackrabbit cache

Tags: artifactory

A few days ago, my Artifactory (version 2.3.2) started reporting error with the datastore garbage collection and with the search, both leading to a root exception thrown by the JackRabbit cache :

```
o.a.j.JcrServiceImpl:1037) - Datastore garbage collector execution failed.
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2
at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.cache.ConcurrentCache.shrinkIfNeeded(ConcurrentCache.java:241) [jackrabbit-core-jfrog-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
```

This morning, Artifactory wasn't responsive at all, so i restarted it, but it failed, and failed again since, with a final exception being :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at java.util.TimeZone.parseCustomTimeZone(TimeZone.java:767) [na:1.6.0_25-ea]
at java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeZone.java:471) [na:1.6.0_25-ea]
at java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeZone.java:465) [na:1.6.0_25-ea]
at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.util.BundleReader.<clinit>(BundleReader.java:56) [jackrabbit-core-jfrog-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
... 82 common frames omitted
```

Jackrabbit seems to be the suspect here, but i'm having a hard time trying to resolve that, hoping on you guys.  =)

By the way, i'm using Derby as metadata store, and i'm using the filesystem for storing the artefacts.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 2.x is not supported anymore (specially because of Jackrabbit problems). 
Version 3 is much faster (up to tens of times) and much more stable. 
Please upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the upgrade was a brutal but a clear solution (i mean, i still dont know what was the problem...). And the import from a previous backup (although from a 2.3.1 version) was a total success ! It conforts me in the choice of Artifactory, and made me want to buy the Pro version.  =)

Comment: I'll give your details to the sales team :)
Just kidding :)